# how to add return two widgets using future builder

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to display two widgets, like a text and after it a table, both contains data from api. i am using stack for it, i created a separate method for table. here is the code

```
Container(
      
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 470, 0, 0),
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    
    child: FutureBuilder(
    
    future: _getRecord(),
   
    
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
      // Check if the data has been received.
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Return the widget and provide the received data.
        if(historyList.length!=0){
              return Stack(children:<Widget>[
                Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(subtitle:Text(snapshot.data[index].date));})),// it is not displaying this line
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                attendanceHistory(snapshot.data)

              ]);
             // return attendanceHistory(snapshot.data);
        }
       
      }
```

`attendanceHistory(snapshot.data)` this line display the table with data, but subtitle is not working

kindly please help how to do this

Comment: what "not working" means?

Comment: means it is not displaying the ```(snapshot.data[index].date)``` value

Comment: and tried to `print(snapshot.data[index].date)`? does it have valid data?

Comment: it is printing now, my bad. but it is printing on the lenght of data for example if data is 10 then it print 10 times, but i want to display it one time at the top of the table, do u know how to do this?

Comment: only one? so why do you use `ListView.builder` then?

Comment: @pskink because api returns only one data of that value, well i resolved the issue.